# How do you use an anchor of a TikZ circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, anchor

I drew a circle with

```
\draw (0,0) circle (3);
```

and I want to put an arrow pointing to the right at the base of it. Something like

```
\draw [-latex] (circle.south) -- ++(2,0);
```

The alternative option would be to manually specify the starting coordinate as

```
\draw [-latex] (0, -3) -- ++(2,0);
```

but to me, this is less than ideal. I don't want to have to think about discrete coordinates if I don't need to. I want to just specify where it goes in relation to something else, as I specified.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 5):

You can make the circle a node.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path (0,0) node[circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=6cm](circle){};
 \draw[-latex] (circle.south) -- ++(2,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why use `\path`? I'm not confident on the purpose of that macro. I thought the macro for creating a node was `\node`.

Comment: @Kalcifer `path` is the "master" command, but you can also use `\node[circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=3cm](circle)at (0,0){};` here to get the same result. `at (0,0)` can be dropped in this case, too.)

Comment: Does `minimum width` refer to the diameter and not the radius in this case?

Comment: @Kalcifer Good catch! Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

You can draw the circle as a full arc from `-90` degrees (=south) to `+270` and then continue with the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-latex] (0,0) arc [start angle=-90,end angle=270,radius=3] -- ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```